# Storing the names and address of people from a file into strings and later on printing them in alphabetic (from the surname)

Tags: c++

In the file `a1.txt`, there are ames of people and their addresses. I am thinking of storing them in strings and then comparing and printing them in alphabetic order. Here is how the information in the file looks:

```
Kitty Garfield
36 Jon Havey Court, Middle, MO 66222
Bill Lake
21 Ritts, Middletown, MI 48788
...The list continues
```

I think I have included everything in the my code shown below but the function does not run.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and CodeBlocks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    string name;
    string address;
};

int getWhatTheyWant();
void displayPeople();
void addPerson();
void searchByLastName();
void printAllSearchedAndFoundPeople();

int main()
{
    int whatTheyWant;

    do
    {
        whatTheyWant = getWhatTheyWant();

        switch (whatTheyWant)
        {
        case 1:
            displayPeople();
            break;
        case 2:
            addPerson();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchByLastName();
            break;
        case 4:
            printAllSearchedAndFoundPeople();
            break;
        case 5: //just not to print the cout statement after
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter something valid" << endl;
        }

    } while (whatTheyWant != 5);

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}

//display
int getWhatTheyWant()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "1-Print people in the alphabetic order" << endl;
    cout << "2- If you want to add people" << endl;
    cout << "3-Search by last name" << endl;
    cout << "4-Print all the peope who are searched and found" << endl;
    cout << "5- Exit the program" << endl;


    cin >> choice;

    return(choice);
}

//printing the people
void displayPeople()
{
    ifstream theFile("a1.txt");

    if (theFile.is_open())
    {
        person x[6];
        string justToGetFromFile;
        string *temporary;

        temporary = new string[12];

        int whereFirstLetterOfSurnameIs[6];
        char whatIsTheFirstLetterOfSurname[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            getline(theFile, justToGetFromFile);
            temporary[i] = justToGetFromFile;
        }

        theFile.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            x[i].name = temporary[2 * i];
            x[i].address = temporary[2 * i + 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            whereFirstLetterOfSurnameIs[i] = x[i].name.find(" ", 0) + 1;
            whatIsTheFirstLetterOfSurname[i] = x[i].name.at(whereFirstLetterOfSurnameIs[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
            {
                if (whatIsTheFirstLetterOfSurname[j - 1] >   whatIsTheFirstLetterOfSurname[j])//comparison as the letters are numbers
                {
                    person temp;
                    temp = x[j];
                    x[j] = x[j - 1];
                    x[j - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            cout << x[i].name << endl << x[i].address << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "you messed it up" << endl;
    }
}

void addPerson()
{

}

void searchByLastName()
{

}

void printAllSearchedAndFoundPeople()
{

}
```

Comment: You've been directed to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before. _"The function does not run"_ is not an adequate description of the problem, most of the code you posted is probably irrelevant to the question (but only probably, because it's not at all clear what your question is), and you are trying to do too many new things in your code at once. Try a simpler problem first.

Comment: @Beta I understand what you mean. "By the function does not run" I mean that I cannot read from the file and store the name and address to the structure, which is made by 2 strings : name and address. I have checked a lot of sites and I think I am missing something in my code. If you can make the function just to save the data from the file into an array of type person I would really appreciate it and I will continue with the other functions.

Comment: @Bixo Like Beta says, you're trying too much at once. Start with just a program that reads from the file and prints the contents. If that works, try parsing the file into `person` objects. If that works, try sorting them. And so on. Don't try everything at once and get stuck because you can't figure out where it's breaking.

Comment: Ouch, I see, just to make smaller function. I will try that. Thank you guys!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error: your code seems to read the file and store the data correctly.

Comment: See the answer for this question for a good and organized way to parse a file in C++.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564384/how-to-parse-in-this-file-in-c-dealing-with-spaces-and-new-lines
You could adapt the answer there to read your file into a std::vector<person>, for instance.