# Get total products number from file

Tags: c++, file

I have the products.txt file:

```
Chocolate Milka 5 250
Soda Fanta 3 2
...
```

As you can see, the data is entered in order: name, manufacturer, price, quantity. I need to write a program that will determine how many products are in the products.txt file.

I tried with:

```
int number_of_lines = 0;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    ++number_of_lines;
std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
```

But as a result it throws out 0. I tried to determine the total number of products using the number of lines in the file, because the number of lines = the number of products?

Comment: I would guess that you failed to open the file correctly, and therefore getline fails, and therefore the line count is zero. But only guessing.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's really impossible to do anything but *guess*.

Comment: [Checking if a file opened successfully with ifstream](//stackoverflow.com/q/6255339)

Answer (score 1):

The code works and as in the comments, you probably could not open the file for some reason (wrong path, read permission, etc).

Try adding an if to check if the file was correctly opened as below

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("products.txt");

  if (myfile) {
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
      ++number_of_lines;
    std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Could not open the file" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But beware that this code is counting the number of lines in the file and not the number of products. Therefore, any empty line will be counted as a product.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564761/1102805) has a very nice way to read and parse a text file in C++ that could be useful to you.

Comment: I have no idea how to calculate the product number in any other way.

Comment: This way is fine if you know your file will not have extra empty lines and only has products. To compute the number of products even if the file has empty lines (or something else) you would need to parse what you are reading with `getline` to check if it is a product or not. The answer that I mentioned has a more general code and could be used even if the file has different things besides products. Or maybe in the future you add a column with a product type and then you want to count the number of products of each type. In that case you will have to parse the file.