# trying to break a line into multiple tokens

Tags: c++

My problem is this, i have this string `RGM 3 13 GName 0005 32 funny 0000 44 teste 0000\n` and i want to split it like this

```
13 GName
32 funny 
44 teste
```

so i can save the numbers and names in an array, but the problem is for some reason declaring an "" like i did is invalid in c++ and it is breaking the line at all.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#define line "RGM 3 13 GName 0005 32 funny 0000 44 teste 0000\n"

int main()
{
    char s[] = "";
    char* token;
    strtok(line,s);
    strtok(line,s);
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        printf( " %s\n", token );
        token = strtok(NULL,s);
    }
   
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `strtok` is kind of deprecated in the C++ world. Also, it's not thread-safe.

Comment: `char s[] = "";` what is the length of `s` here? (remember that primitive arrays have static size in C++)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Comment: You are mixing C++ (`#include <iostream>`) and C (the rest of the code). That is a pretty bad idea. From what I see, you are using C, so maybe you should retag your question.

Comment: For a C++ solution to these problems a good approach is the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564761/1102805).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your lines are always going to have the format `A B n1 str1 code1 ... nn strn coden`, where you seem to discard `A B`, the simple C++ code below will suffice:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/rqvs5TMjT)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string line{"RGM 3 13 GName 0005 32 funny 0000 44 teste 0000"};

    std::istringstream iss{line};

    std::string token1{};
    std::string token2{};
    iss >> token1 >> token2; // get rid of header (RGM 3)

    std::string token3{};
    while (iss >> token1 >> token2 >> token3)
    {
        std::cout << token1 << " " << token2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Notice this is doing almost no checks at all. Should you need more control over your input, something more advanced could be implemented.

For example, the code below, using regular expressions, would try to match each line header to a `RGM m` (`RGM` text and 1-digit `m`); then, it would search for groups of the form `n str code` (2-digit `n`, alphabetic `str`, 4-digit `code`):

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/qvK8MdvT3)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <regex>  // regex_search, smatch
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line{"RGM 3 13 GName 0005 32 funny 0000 44 teste 0000"};

    std::regex header_pattern{R"(RGM\s+\d)"};
    std::regex group_pattern{R"(\s+(\d{2})\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\d{4})"};
    std::smatch matches{};
    if (std::regex_search(line, matches, header_pattern))
    {
        line = matches.suffix();
        while (std::regex_search(line, matches, group_pattern))
        {
            std::cout << matches[1] << " " << matches[2] << "\n";
            line = matches.suffix();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

strtok modifies the string passed to it, so passing a string literal is undefined behavior

so instead declare

```
char line[] = "RGM 3 13 GName 0005 32 funny 0000 44 teste 0000\n";
```

when you look at the prototype you get a hint about that

```
char* strtok( char* str, const char* delim );
```

so the first arg is not const in any way